# Why doesn't $P(A\cup B \cap C) = P(A) + P(B\cap C) - P(A\cap B \cap C)$?

Tags: probability

> Why doesn't $P(A\cup B \cap C) = P(A) + P(B\cap C) - P(A\cap B \cap C)$?

I understand that this isn't true looking at a Venn diagram, but mathematically it doesn't make sense if $P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$.

Comment: It is true if the left side is $P(A\cup(B\cap C))$, but this is $P((A\cup B)\cap C)$.

Comment: More generally, $A\cup (B\cap C)\neq (A\cup B)\cap C.$

Comment: Looks true to me, under a reasonable assumption about what $A \cup B \cap C$ means. What makes you think it's not true?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Why do you say that it is $P((A\cup B)\cap C)$? If we agree that there is a rule, intersections should always come first (as with the usual operations). Otherwise, we should agree that there is no rule.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. I didn't know that order mattered. Thank you very much!

Comment: I know of no standard "order of operations" between $\cup$ and $\cap,$ which means "left to right" is the default.  @JohnB In any event, the OP said that when he draws the venn diagram, it is obviously false, so I suspect the OP is interpreting it as left-to-right when drawing the Venn diagram.

Comment: And why do you think $\cap$ is like $\times$ and $\cup$ is like $+?.$  $+$ and $\times$ and exponentiation rise in complexity, while $\cap$ and $\cup$ are dual operations - neither primary. @JohnB

Comment: Gonna have to provide a reference better than just "I say so." @JohnB

Comment: Actually you should provide some reference for the unsupported claim in your first comment that it is in the other way. Why should it be as you say?

Comment: That's absurd. You have only asserted it is the canon. I also assert that my impression of the facts is the canon. And I gave a reason why neither should be given precedence. "I declared it canon first" is hardly an argument. If it is canon, you should be able to provide some evidence or a reason.  This answer suggests $\cap$ and $\cup$ are at the same precedence level. I haven't found any page that agrees with your assertion. https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-precedence-of-set-operations @JohnB

Comment: @JohnB Another example: "1. Evaluate complement first
2. Evaluate $\cup$ and $\cap$ second." https://www.uow.edu.au/~bmaloney/wuct121/LogicWeek8Lecture1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It is true that $$P(X\cup Y) = P(X)+P(Y)-P(X\cap Y).\tag{1}$$

And if we substitute $X=A, Y=B\cap C$ blindly, that would seem to mean:

$$P(A\cup B\cap C) = P(A)+P(B\cap C) - P(A\cap B\cap C).$$

But that is an improper substitution. In the text, we have to substitute $(B\cap C)$ into the formula for $Y.$

---

**A numeric example**

We know that $3\times 2 = 6$ and that $2=1+1.$ But we can't just replace the string $2$ in the first expression with the string $1+1$ and get:

$$3\times 1+1 = 6\quad\color{red}{\text{wrong}}$$

We have to replace $2$ by $(1+1)$ to get:

$$3\times(1+1) = 6\quad \color{green}{\text{correct}}$$

---

So it is true that, from $(1)$, we get:

$$P(A\cup(B\cap C))=P(A)+P(B\cap C) - P(A\cap B\cap C)$$

but it is **not** true that:

$$P((A\cup B)\cap C) =P(A)+P(B\cap C) - P(A\cap B\cap C)$$

and $A\cup B\cap C$ is normally interpreted as $(A\cup B)\cap C,$ and it is not, in general, true that:

$$(A\cup B)\cap C=A\cup (B\cap C).$$

---

The standard notation we use, where we put operators like $+$ and $\times$ and $\cap$ and $\cup$ in between operands is called "infix notation." Infix notation does not play well with string substitution.

Another notation, *reverse Polish notation,* actually does okay with string substitutions. If we write $3,2,\times = 6$ and $2=1,1,+$ then we can replace the $2$ in the first expression with $1,1,+$ and still get a valid equality:

$$3,1,1,+,\times=6$$

(I  use infix $=$ because $=$ is not a operator, but we could be more pedantic.)

Comment: There's a typo in $(1)$, last term should be substracting...

Comment: Thanks @leonbloy